# How do I fix the camera roll to its parent object? Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, camera, tracking, parent

I have a space ship that follows a path across my scene with a few cameras to record it. One camera I would like to use for a sort of point of view effect when the ship enters a barrel roll, however, the camera does not roll with the ship.

Currently the camera is parented to an empty that tracks another empty just in front of the ship:

[image]

The camera empty and its target are parented to the ship so when the ship rotates I had assumed all of its children would too, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Things doing what they aren't supposed to:

[image]

My web of an outliner:

[image]

Looking back now I can see how moving the scene around the camera/ship might have been preferable but now I'm in too deep so I hope one of you can help.

Side note this is my first post so critique is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you could really easily just keayframe the rotation seperatly right? just go to the frames were you set your keyframes for the spaceship, copy all the rotation values, imput them in to your camera, and add a keyframe for rotation only